# Calculating surface area of intersection of surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Suppose we consider surface $S$ of $z = g(x,y)$ where $(x,y)$ belongs to a suitable domain $D$ then the surface area is given by the formula
$$
Area = \int\int_D \sqrt{g_x^2 + g_y^2 +1} \, dA
$$
where $g_x$ and $g_y$ denote partial derivatives of $g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Now if we consider two surfaces,
$$
z = g(x,y) \text{ and } z = h(x,y)
$$
where $(x,y) \in D$ then what is the surface area of the surface formed by the intersection of $z= g(x,y)$ and $z= h(x,y)$?

Some examples :

If I consider $z = h(x,y) = c $ where $c$ is some constant (we assume that this plane intersects with $z = g(x,y)$) then life becomes easy. The area will be
$$\int\int \sqrt{g_x^2 + g_y^2 +1} \, dA
$$ integrated over the region $g(x,y) = c$ in $D$.

How to deal with general case?
(Continuity and differentibilty of $g$ and $h$ can be assumed for simplicity)

Comment: Hint: In most cases the intersection of two surfaces will be a curve.

Comment: @Benjamin in our first case we had area element $dS = \sqrt{g_x^2+g_y^2+1} dxdy$. I am not getting how to calculate it in general case.

Comment: @ak1972 Hint: What is the (2-dimensional) area of a (1-dimensional) curve?